# How to install wamp and instantrails together on the same machine?

Tags: wampserver

Hi I have wamp installed on my system and I want to install instantrails too which also comes with mysql and apache... Can I install both (wamp & instantrails) together on the same machine without any confliction between each other??

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any conflict **as long as they are listening on different ports**. That aside, the Apache and MySQL installations will be in different directories (WAMP will install them in `C:\WAMP\` for instance), and they will each run their own Apache and MySQL instances as different services. The only thing you will have to potentially contend with is the port conflicts, but this can be reconfigured.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. Can you please tell me one more thing.. Would it be even better if I install them on different drives??

Comment: @dhirajkarn It won't make a difference, because they'll install their instances of Apache and MySQL inside their own folders.